# The tag [lazyload] should be a tag-synonym for [lazy-loading]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

We have a tag [lazy-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazy-loading) with over 4.6k questions. We even have an existing synonym: [lazy-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazy-load).

At some point yet another variation was created: [lazyload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazyload), which has been used on over 150 questions, so far.

This tag should be made a synonym to the main one. Its existence only confuses matters.

Comment: Are you certain that “lazyload” is not the name of some specific function, API, or library?

Comment: Comparing the tag info for each, I'd say they are about the same thing.

Comment: And the questions for "lazyload" do not seem to be focused on any library that I could see.

Comment: Yeah, not the tag description. That's never really a useful thing to check. Nobody fills those in, least of all the people uninterested in tag curation. But you do have to look at the questions with the tag, and make sure that it's not a legitimate tag in disguise because it actually refers to some specific, oddly-named thing.